# Как работать с файлами?

Tags: django

models.py:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='images')
```

views.py:

```
with open('static/test.png','w') as f:
    from django.core.files import File
    Image.objects.create(file=File(f))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 3, in 
>     File "C:\Users\Horoshiy\Documents\willbe\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
>       return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Horoshiy\Documents\willbe\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 422, in create
>       obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
>     File "C:\Users\Horoshiy\Documents\willbe\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 741, in save
>       force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
>     File "C:\Users\Horoshiy\Documents\willbe\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 779, in save_base
>       force_update, using, update_fields,
>     File "C:\Users\Horoshiy\Documents\willbe\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 870, in _save_table
>       result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
>     File "C:\Users\Horoshiy\Documents\willbe\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
>       using=using, raw=raw)
>     File "C:\Users\Horoshiy\Documents\willbe\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
>       return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Horoshiy\Documents\willbe\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1186, in _insert
>       return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
>     File "C:\Users\Horoshiy\Documents\willbe\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1334, in execute_sql
>       for sql, params in self.as_sql():
>     File "C:\Users\Horoshiy\Documents\willbe\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1278, in as_sql
>       for obj in self.query.objs
>     File "C:\Users\Horoshiy\Documents\willbe\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1278, in 
>       for obj in self.query.objs
>     File "C:\Users\Horoshiy\Documents\willbe\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1277, in 
>       [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
>     File "C:\Users\Horoshiy\Documents\willbe\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1228, in pre_save_val
>       return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
>     File "C:\Users\Horoshiy\Documents\willbe\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 288, in pre_save
>       file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)
>     File "C:\Users\Horoshiy\Documents\willbe\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 87, in save
>       self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
>     File "C:\Users\Horoshiy\Documents\willbe\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 52, in save
>       return self._save(name, content)
>     File "C:\Users\Horoshiy\Documents\willbe\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 270, in _save
>       for chunk in content.chunks():
>     File "C:\Users\Horoshiy\Documents\willbe\django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\base.py", line 60, in chunks
>       data = self.read(chunk_size)
>   io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: Рискну предположить, что, если уж ошибка `not readable`, стоит открыть файл для чтения, а не записи: `with open('static/test.png','r') as f:`

Comment: @V-Mor да, тупая ошибка... Но теперь сохраненные файлы в images весят по 0 байт,

Comment: наверно потому, что я стер оригинал до этого...

Comment: Это уже стоит вынести в отдельный вопрос

Answer (score 1):

В тексте ошибки встречается текст `not readable`, что свидетельствует о нечитаемости файла, т.к. он открыт для записи. Нужно открыть файл для чтения:

`with open('static/test.png','r') as f:`

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот нужно было, чтобы не было никаких ошибок:

```
with open('static/test.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    from django.core.files import File
    d_f = File(f, name='testic.jpg')
    Image.objects.create(file=d_f)
```